# 'make' command does not work while installing wine from source on pi 2

Tags: pi-2, software-installation

Following [these steps](https://www.winehq.org/site/docs/wineusr-guide/installing-wine-source), I tried to install wine from source, running `sudo apt-get install wine1.6` or `sudo apt-get install wine-1.6` never worked. I tried looking for answers on this [fourm](https://www.skial.com/threads/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-12-04.42154/) and the last reply was the only answer I could try.

So I followed the steps and opened terminal as root. I navigated to the folder with the files and ran `./configure`, no errors. I go and run `make depend` but instantly fires back `make: *** No rule to make target 'depend'. Stop.` this happened with the other make commands.

Specs:

Raspberry Pi 2

Runninh Ubuntu MATE with 32GB SDHC card

Comment: Adding to @Milliways comment you may want to look at mono depending on what your use case is.

Answer (score 3):

You are wasting your time! `wine` is a Windows API layer for x86 Linux machines. It will NOT RUN on ARM.

Comment: Are you sure? It was my initial reaction too, but started to doubt when I looked at https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wine and saw for stretch (and sid) 'all' for the architecture list. Looking at the dependencies of https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wine I saw https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wine32 and at https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wine32#pdownload I see `armhf` ...

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas Unless `wine` has drastically changed from when I wrote some patches for it years ago "`wine` is not an emulator".

Comment: I'm very much inclined to believe you, but there are even package on raspbian :-O http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wine/  I have no interest in windows/wine whatsoever myself, but it may be worth a try for ppl who are interested.

Comment: Unless someone has grafted on an x86 emulator, this would at best work for windows executables built for a compatible arm architecture that is actually supported by wine.  Do you have some?  Yes, there's some nonsense floating around about a windows version for the pi, but chances are that it is both not what the poster had in mind, and probably would be incompatible anyway.